# Finding AUC through cross-validation on training data in H2O Stacked Ensemble

Tags: python, cross-validation, h2o, ensemble-learning

I would like to find the ensemble performance of the training data in H2O stacked ensemble. In the link -python code, it showed the performance (AUC) of the test data, however, I need to see the performance of the train data (Mean of the results of the each fold). Is there any options available to do that?
[code](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html)

Comment: are you referring to this link: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html?

Comment: Thanks @Lauren. Yes I'm referring to this link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the performance on the training data you can either just type in the ensemble object and press enter

`ensemble`

and it will give you all the metrics or you can do

`ensemble.auc()`

which will default to the training metrics. (code example snippet can be found [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/stacked-ensembles.html)).

(quick note, however, to understand the performance of your ensemble you should really look at the performance on a new test data set or at the cross-validation metrics. The training evaluation metric (AUC in your case), is not going to tell you how well your model will generalize on new data.)

Comment: Thank you so much @Lauren. Yap, in my case, I've got AUC about 99.99 % for the training data (cross-validated results with K = 5). Surprisingly, it's much more better than the other ML methods that I explored earlier. I understand that it's just the performance of the training data that will be different for the unseen data / test data.

Comment: Thank you very much @Lauren. If I'm correct ensemble.auc () shows the AUC value of the training data (not the cross-validated AUC).To get the cross-validation metrics i.e AUC,  I've to write  `ensemble.auc(xval = True) `  and for cross-validated performance I've to write  `ensemble.model_performance(xval=True)`.  <br/> For base learners it works  however, for stacked ensemble it shows none. Please see code: (https://imgur.com/D2lkaPu).

Comment: It seems that we cannot evaluate the stacked ensemble on the cross-validation data. Any suggestions, as I need to compare the cross-validated results (i.e. AUC) from Base learners and stacked ensemble?